# SVG. Разный цвет текста

Tags: svg

Можно как-то в одном элементе "text" выделить разные участники разным цветом? Пример из ворда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закрыто

```
<text><tspan fill="#ff0000">Красный</tspan><tspan fill="#00ff00">Зеленый</tspan></text>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://css.yoksel.ru/css-and-svg-masks/

Посмотрите может, как нибудь поможет...

P.S. Это не совсем решение проблемы, но если оно Вам подошло, оцените это как ответ...